# Appending data to existing CSV file by columns/rows

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to export data into csv. When I export it, it is exported as a singular row and each additional data is appended on the same row. The result is a very long row which is difficult to navigate.

The goal is for each value (Time, Wallets) to have their own column and each time the script is ran, the new data is appended to the csv under the respective column. I have tried guides online but wasn't able to find any solutions.

Here is my code if anyone has any suggestions or ideas. Additionally, if anyone has any suggestions for restructuring my code or making it better, I'd love to hear it. As a beginner I would like to learn as much as possible.

```
#Open ChromeDriver
PATH = ('/Users/chris/Desktop/chromedriver')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

#Get Website 

driver.get("https://bitinfocharts.com/top-100-richest-dogecoin-addresses.html")
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.maximize_window()

#Creates the Time
now = datetime.now()
current_time = now.strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S ")


#Identify the section of page
time.sleep(3)
page = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'.table.table-condensed.bb')


#Gather the data
time.sleep(3)
num_of_wallets = page.find_element(By.XPATH, "//html/body/div[5]/table[1]/tbody/tr[10]/td[2]").text

#Write to CSV


table_dict = {"Time":current_time,
            "Wallets":num_of_wallets}

headers = ["Time", "Wallets"]

file = open('dogedata.csv', 'a')
file.write(f'{current_time},{num_of_wallets}')
file.close()
```

Comment: Have you looked into using a Pandas Dataframe to store your data? It's very easy to then export that to a csv as you want (see the docs [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html#pandas-dataframe-to-csv))

Comment: Add a `file.write('\n')` before your current `file.close()`. This should create a new line whenever you write

Comment: You should use the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv) module in the standard library to create the file. It's built-in, debugged, and easy to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *smallest* fix, as Shubham P. pointed out, is to make sure you are writing a "line" by including a line break, like `'\n'`:

```py
file = open('dogedata.csv', 'a')
file.write(f'{current_time},{num_of_wallets}\n')
file.close()
```

The *far better* fix, as martineau pointed out, is to use the **csv** module: it's standard, well-developed and used, and importantly takes care of issues like escaping and quoting characters, and it only takes one more line:

```py
file = open('dogedata.csv', 'a', newline='')
writer = csv.writer(f)
writer.writerow([current_time, num_of_wallets])
file.close()
```

Note that `newline=''` was added to the `open()` function, which tells open() not to handle newlines, and instead defer to the **writer** which has CSV-specific smarts for dealing w/newlines.

Also, instead of using string formatting, you just wrap your data in a list (`[current_time, num_of_wallets]`); the writer will convert everything to strings/text.